# Run multiple debug instances at once in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

Eclipse will happily let me launch my application in the debugger multiple times, so I have several instances of the app running at once - great for networked apps.

BUT, I can't see how to toggle between the instances... I got a situation where one instance was paused and another took over for a breakpoint, and I couldn't get back to resume the first one.

Also they seem to share the same console for output... is that something I can adjust?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No all instance will have their own console for output. And to switch between different debug instances use *Debug* view. There you will see list of debug instances and whichever you click will get enabled at that time.

[image]

As in above image there are 2 debug instance of Demo class. But the 1st is currently active.

Comment: D'oh, so obvious! Thanks for the quick answer.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by making a copy of the entire workspace folder and launching a separate copy of eclipse using the cloned workspace.